# RemoteObject - Cross Domain Issue

Tags: apache-flex, xml-rpc

I am trying to get data from my server, used RemoteObject to accomplish it.
When I run the application on my localhost it works great but when iam using it on my server i get a Channel.Security.Error(Security Error accessing URL).

On the server side logs there is a mention about cross domain .
77.127.194.4 - - [23/Oct/2008 21:15:11] "GET /crossdomain.xml HTTP/1.1" 501

Any one encountered the same problem ? any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add to your crossdomain.xml (where your fetching the stuff from) this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.YOUR_FRAME_WORK_CROSSDOMAIN_POLICY.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
    <cross-domain-policy>
        <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
        <allow-access-from domain="*.YOUR_SITE_GOES_HERE.com" secure="false" />
        <allow-access-from domain="*.YOUR_SITE_GOES_HERE.com" secure="false" />
    </cross-domain-policy>
```

The stuff in capslock you'll probably have to change to fit your framework. For example i copied that from the one i use with macromedia flash. Instead of "www.YOUR_FRAME_WORK_CROSSDOMAIN_POLICY.com/..." i normaly have "www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/...

I'm not sure but try to investigate that, it's probably your problem. For cross-domain, you normaly need to add to the server side, where your fecthing stuff from, permission for other sites to get it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. You are right about crossdomain.xml file, but unfortunately, the Python SimpleXMLRPCServer library does not support the GET method by default, so we need to implement this.

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

class ExtendedXMLRPCRequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    #only allow a request for the crossdomain file
    if self.path != '/crossdomain.xml':
      self.send_response(403)
      self.log_request(403)
      return

    #open the crossdomain file and read its contents
    response = open('crossdomain.xml', 'r').read()

    #write the data to the socket along with valid HTTP headers
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/xml")
    self.send_header("Content-length", str(len(response)))
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(response)
    self.log_request(200)
```